# importError: No module named django.db

Tags: django, models

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

def Article(models.Model):
   title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
   body=models.TextField()
   pub_date=models.DateTimeField('date published')
   likes=models.IntegerField()

   def __unicode__(self):
      return self.title
```

This is my code
I am using Django 1.8.2 
I am within virtual environment

Comment: Please, run python under virtualenv and try to execute the following code: `import django`. If this works, show, please, how do you run the project using `manage.py`.

Comment: did you activate your virtualenv? if so, can you check for django using pip freeze?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you create a simple project?

> django-admin.py startproject nameofyourproject
>
> mkdir apps
>
> cd apps
>
> django-admin.py startapp nameofyourapp
>
> add in settings in variable "Installed Apps" your new app

nothing should fail...

Answer (score 0):

can you activate your virtual environment. And make sure django is install in your virtual environment by using following command.

```
pip freeze
```

out put of pip freeze

```
(Dev-Env)➜  django_chat git:(singleUserChat) pip freeze
Django==1.7.1
```